# How do I setup a mvc route with two parameters?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to take a url that looks like this

```
competitors/edit/d2d01443-118c-4a35-a783-465505f8d786?accountid=6af99691-2275-4629-8542-2eb52a34893f
```

and convert it to something like this.  Essentially taking just moving the account id parameter before the competitor parameter.

```
/competitors/edit/6af99691-2275-4629-8542-2eb52a34893f/d2d01443-118c-4a35-a783-465505f8d786
```

I've tried adding this route to the top of the route config but I just get a 404 error when I try the new url.  Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Competitors",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{accountid}/id",
        defaults: new { controller = "Competitors", action = "Edit", accountid = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need braces around all your segments, otherwise "id" would need to be hardcoded into the URL for it to match:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Competitors",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{accountid}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Competitors", action = "Edit", accountid = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```